# How to add recoilize debugger to react 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs, react-18

I used 'create-react-app', installed "recoil", and tried a simple example [here](https://github.com/open-source-labs/Recoilize).
Then I tried to add [recoil debugger](https://npm.io/package/recoilize) to the chrome extension. But it doesn't work and the app crashes with an error. I assume it is because the example is written with "ReactDOM.render" syntax, but React 18 uses "root.render".

Does anyone know how to fix it?

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import RecoilizeDebugger from 'recoilize';
import { RecoilRoot } from 'recoil';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RecoilRoot>
      <App />
      <RecoilizeDebugger />r
    </RecoilRoot>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAV9U.png)

Comment: it seems there is no support yet - https://github.com/open-source-labs/Recoilize/issues/158

Comment: You need to add the image to the question itself instead of providing a link which will be broken over time.